# How can you retrieve a UTC DateTime from Postgresql using Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, datetime, npgsql

I am using the "timestamp with time zone" column type and setting my datetimes like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1)
VALUES(timestamp with time zone '2020-07-16 17:45:00.000000+00');
```

Whenever I try and retrieve my DateTimes they are being converted to the 'local' kind.

This is not what I want, its set as a UTC datetime and I want it back as UTC, I do not want it converting to local going into the database, nor coming back out ... doing so makes it impossible to get to UTC without causing ambiguity.

I have tried setting the "PGTZ" environment variable; I have also executed the following sql when the connection opens:

```
Connection.ExecuteAsync( "SET TIMEZONE TO 'UTC'" );
```

Nothing I have tried seems to work and it seems to be by-design according to various posts like:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/347

This seems utterly wrong to me, but I am hoping someone can point me to a workaround for this.

I am using .net5/asp.net and Dapper (not EFCore) and Npgsql version 4.1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed by design, and matches the PostgreSQL when querying timestamptz values in regular text queries. If you use fire up psql or pgadmin and select a timestamptz column, you'll see a local timestamp based on on your `TimeZone` session parameter.

As mentioned by @adrian-klaver, timestamptz isn't about storing the timezone in the database - it's about applying timezone conversions when reading and writing timestamp values to the database, based on the `TimeZone` parameter. If you don't want any such conversions, consider switching to timestamp (without time zone), and having all timestamps as UTC by convention.

Comment: Thanks @Shay, I read that if you want to store UTC values you should use the `timestamp with time zone` but I didnt consider that as I am controlling things via code then i can ensure its utc before I set the value. I must say, out of all the dbs, postgres seems overly complicated in this regard and prone to misteps so thanks for clarifying

Comment: I agree that PG is a bit confusing (although FWIW it just seems to be following the SQL standard very closely). You may want to read [this comment of mine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/what-is-a-valid-use-case-for-using-timestamp-without-time-zone/215563#215563) on timestamp with and without timezone; I'd really recommend going with "UTC by convention"

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql `timestamptz` does not actually store the timezone, it just stores the values as at UTC. This means `'2020-07-16 17:45:00.000000+00'` will not transformed to UTC on entry. Without a specified time zone it would be rotated from the `TimeZone` setting to `UTC`. On retrieval though it will use the `TimeZone` setting to rotate back to that time zone.  I suspect your setting is not happening in the same session that the timestamp retrieval is taking place. I would try something like `SELECT timestamp_fld AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`